# Is user in active directly group

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, active-directory, ldap

How do I find out a user is part of an active directly group DOMAIN\Object_Modify from C++ under Windows.

I prefer a solution not using COM, do I need to connect via LDAP directly?

Comment: From C++, it seems to be either COM or directly into the LDAP api, which doesn't need COM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367016(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You could use WMI https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384689(v=vs.85).aspx